# Test using rest assured , body correctly sent but not read by application

Tags: java, spring, rest-assured

I m using rest assured with latest version of java spring.
I try to simulate call to authenticate with post method and json body (contentType is application/json) but when my request is intercepted by my java spring application, the body is empty.. and my authenticate methods throw a 401.. this behavior is correct. But the empty body isn't.

I can see with ngrep and some functions with rest assured that all request are correctly done.

**When i use curl,postman or ajax from js client i don't have this problem**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserControllerImplTest {
    @Test
    public void testUserAuthenticateWitParams200() {

        Map<String, Object> jsonAsMap = new HashMap<>();
        jsonAsMap.put("email", "groschat.eu@gmail.com");
        jsonAsMap.put("password", "groschat93**");

        given().log().all()
                .body(jsonAsMap)
                .contentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8").
        when()

.post(String.format("http://localhost:%s/api/users/authenticate", port))
                .peek().
        then()
                .statusCode(is(200));
    }
}
```

Here is the log from peek() function :

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://localhost:53850/api/users/authenticate
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/* Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "password": "groschat93**",
    "email": "groschat.eu@gmail.com"
}
```

Here is the request from dev tool inside chrome

Request headers:

```
POST /api/users/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: back-spring.dev
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 62
Origin: https://front.dev
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: https://front.dev/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Request Payload:

```
{"email":"martinbryan.eu@gmail.com","password":"groschat93**"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was Tomcat and a useless semicolon in the header Content-Type.
Tomcat wasn't able to read the content type with the semicolon with nothing following like charset. So when the request was read, server side, the default content type text/plain. RestAssured

So i changed tomcat by undertow and i don't use rest assured anymore but WebTestClient. See codes and pom.xml. Source of this problem wasn't expected.

```
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes={
            server_spring.Application.class,
            server_spring.config.WebSecurityConfig.class,
            server_spring.config.GlobalConfiguration.class,
            server_spring.config.MvcConfig.class,
            server_spring.config.WebConfig.class
    })
public class UserControllerImplTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    public void testWithAnotherMethod() {
        Map<String, String> jsonMap = new HashMap();
        jsonMap.put("email","martinbryan.eu@gmail.com");
        jsonMap.put("password","groschat93**");

        webClient
            .post()
            .uri("/api/users/authenticate")
            .header("Origin","https://front.dev")
            .header("Referer","https://front.dev")
            .header("Host", "back-spring.dev")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(jsonMap))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```